# Comparison of two strings

Tags: java, string, reverse

I have the following code:

```
    int t = s.length()-1;
    int g = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++){

        if (s.charAt(i) != h.charAt(t--));
            g++;

    }

    if (g==0)
        return true;

    else 
        return false;
```

Basically what this code is suppose to do is to test if string h's inverse is equal to string s, or vice versa. For some reason a "false" is always returned - although the obvious answer is true.

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: What you expected? and What you get?

Comment: @Javed I expect to get a true, but i keep getting a false. For example: ATG VS GTA - this need to be true ; ATG VS TAG - this need to be false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say an extra `;` is the culprit.

Instead of

```
if (s.charAt(i) != h.charAt(t--));
```

use

```
if (s.charAt(i) != h.charAt(t--))
```

You should always go the "safe" route. That is, use braces after *if-else* statements (and pretty much everywhere you can use them), so bugs like this won't happen in the first place. The correct way to write it is:

```
if (s.charAt(i) != h.charAt(t--)) {
   g++;
}
```

And by the way, your code will blow up if you don't check first that `s` and `h` have the same length.

Comment: @Nikita: true. Mandatory braces in Java Language Specification would make some people scream in anger, but also the total number of bugs in Java code in the world would be reduced.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved the problem. The two strings will always be the same length. String h is string s before characters in it have been changed. So it will always be the same. Thanks a lot, it was a valuable lesson!

Comment: unfortunately there is nothing that stops you from writing `if (condition); { do-it-always; }`

Comment: @Piotr: no matter what rules exist, someone will find a way to break them.

Answer (score 3):

extra `;` in `if (s.charAt(i) != h.charAt(t--));` may create the issue

Use

```
if (s.charAt(i) != h.charAt(t--))
{
  g++;
  break; // if not match, not need to continue with loop
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think your last if statement will work. What if all the characters is different except one or two? Then it won't work, right?

Comment: Ok, I see you have changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a learning exercise, I'd recommend you avoid writing the loops yourself and use some library code. You can do:

```
String s = "abcd";
String h = "dcba";

System.out.println( h.equals( new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString() ) );
```

or [StringUtils#reverse](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#reverse%28java.lang.String%29).

---

Under the hood, these loop through the string in much the same way that you were doing.  The code is in [AbstractStringBuilder](http://kickjava.com/src/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.htm), if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: Nope, its two different strings, but they are equal in length.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks. Will you please explain what the code do? I knew there's a way of doing it with StringBuffer, but I rather used my method - I'm in my early stages of learning java, I don't want to use too much functions too quickly.

Comment: It's a learning exercise yes. But I'm sure it's better to rather use pre-coded stuff in a program. Thanks for the tip! I'll be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

use `break;` to come out of the loop if it don't have same char

```
bool g = true;
for(.....)
{
   if (s.charAt(i) != h.charAt(t--))
   {
      g = false;
      break;
   }
}
return g;
```

It increases your performance

Comment: Going even further the optimization route, using `boolean g` would probably be faster.

Comment: You can optimize it further by comparing string lengths